# Java string index out of bound , CharAt problem

Tags: java, exception

my code is throwing an error "String index out of bound : 1"  , here is the code :

```
     package inlamningsuppgift2;
        import java.util.Random;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        import java.lang.Math;
        
        public class inlamningsuppgift2del2 {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 01-99");
            
            randomNumber();
            
            
            
        }
        
            public static void randomNumber () {
    
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();
            
        int value = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    
        String str1 = Integer.toString(value);
        String sa = String.format("%02d", value);
    
    
            int randomNum = 10 * random.nextInt(9);
                int randomNum2 = 1 * random.nextInt(9) +1;
                int wholeNum = randomNum + randomNum2;
                String str2 = Integer.toString(randomNum + randomNum2);
                String s = String.format("%02d", randomNum + randomNum2);
    
    
    System.out.println("You guessed :" + sa);
    System.out.println("The correct number is : " + s);
        if (str2.charAt(0) == str1.charAt(0) && str2.charAt(1) == str1.charAt(1)) {
       System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed the right number in the right order and won 1000$!");
    }
        
    else if (str1.charAt(0) == str2.charAt(1) && str1.charAt(1) == str2.charAt(0) ) {
    System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed the right number but in the wrong order and won 500$ !");
    }
    else if (str2.charAt(0) == str1.charAt(0) && str2.charAt(1) != str1.charAt(1)
    || str2.charAt(0) != str1.charAt(0) && str2.charAt(1) == str1.charAt(1)
    || str1.charAt(1) == str2.charAt(0) && str1.charAt(0) != str2.charAt(1)
    || str1.charAt(0) == str2.charAt(1) && str1.charAt(1) != str2.charAt(0)) {
    System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed one of the numbers right!");
    }
    
 else {
    System.out.println("Sorry you guessed wrong, try again");
    }
    }
    }
```

The assignment instructions are : "A lottery program generates a double digit number between 01-99. If the user guesses the number right in the right order, they win 1000$. If the user guesses the right number in the wrong order, example 16 instead of 61, they win 500$. If the user guesses one of the numbers right, they win 100$."

The code is working fine when user input and/or randomNum are 10 and above. However ,when it is below 10 , the error occurs because the value is read as 1 char instead of 2, example : 09 is read as 9 , so charAt(1) does not exist.

How can I fix this? Is there a way to make 0 count as charAt(0) so that charAt(1) counts the digits after the 0,  or do I need to change something else?

Thanks!

Comment: You should just compare numbers directly either with a simple `==` for primitive `int` or the `equals` method for `Integer`. Converting your numbers to Strings and then those Strings to chars and comparing those chars is needlessly complicated and will introduce problems you are currently experiencing.

Comment: You have `String sa = String.format("%02d", value);` but you use `str1` in the main code. Use `sa` instead which will have 2 chars even if the number is less than 10.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thanks for the advice, I will think about that in the future,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments: You have `String sa = String.format("%02d", value);` but you use `str1` in the main code. Use `sa` instead which will have 2 chars even if the number is less than 10.

Another option is to not use strings. Here is a math only version.

```
public static void randomNumber () {
{
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 01-99");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
                
    int value = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    // TODO: add a check 1 <= value <= 99
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(98) + 1;
    
    System.out.printf("You guessed :%02d%n", value);
    System.out.printf("The correct number is : %02d%n", randomNum);
    
    // Check for exact match
    if (value == randomNum) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed the right number in the right order and won 1000$!");
        return;
    }
    
    // Get the digits of the random number (works for single digit numbers, too)
    int randOnes = randomNum % 10;
    int randTens = randomNum / 10;

    // Check for reverse match
    if (value == (randOnes * 10 + randTens)) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed the right number but in the wrong order and won 500$ !");
        return;
    }
    
    // Get user's digits
    int userOnes = value % 10;
    int userTens = value / 10;

    // Check for single digit match
    if (userOnes == randOnes || userOnes == randTens || userTens == randOnes || userTens == randTens) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed one of the numbers right!");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Sorry you guessed wrong, try again");
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I'm new to java and the string version was the one that I was able to do, to fix the problem I posted I did as you said and replaced str with sa, also replaced str2 with s